# Uncertainty on a mean with individual measurement uncertainties

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics

Let's say I measure the diameter $(x)$ of five checkers pieces, using a ruler with a precision of $\pm 0.5mm$, and get the following results:

$x_1 = 50 \pm 0.5mm, \; x_2 = 51 \pm 0.5mm, \; x_3 = 48 \pm 0.5mm, \; x_4 = 50 \pm 0.5mm, \; x_5 = 49 \pm 0.5mm$

The average length of the checkers pieces is then $\bar x = 49.6 mm$, with a standard error on the mean of $\sigma_x = 0.51$. I could therefore quote my mean value as $\bar x = 49.6 \pm 0.51 \,[mm]$

How do I incorporate my measurement uncertainties? Should I just propagate them through the calculation of the mean, or is there another approach?

Comment: As a follow-up, when is it more appropriate to quote the standard deviation as my uncertainty, as supposed to the standard error on the mean?

Comment: Welcome aivmh to Physics SE.  Have you looked at the answers to similar questions such as: [Uncertainty in Repetitive Measurements](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/459184/145491) or [What is the standard way to find averages of measurement values that contain statistic and systematic uncertainties?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28177/145491)?