# Error propagation rounding

Tags: error-analysis

hope I am right in this section.

I am unsure with error propagation. When calculation the error in a titration, many errors has to be taken into account:

Error in Glassware/ Error in Balance/ Error in Burette etc.

I learned that the absolute and relative error have only 1 significant figure and that the total amount is rounded to the decimal place of the error.

Therefore 5.34532g ± 0.001428g would be 5.345g ± 0.001g

The relative error is 0.001g/5.345g = 0.00018709 = 0.0002
If there is an experiment with a lot of steps and error propagation wouldn't the rounding of all the errors in every single step change the result a lot? Wouldn't rounding the error just in the end make more sense?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking if I round the errors during error propagation, I will round up. That way, you are sure to not end up with an error smaller than you should have. If you believe your error to then be bigger than it should be, try rounding to a more precise figure when rounding the errors. In the case of your example above, I don't understand anything of what you're talking about so I can't comment on your error propagation/rounding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why propagation of uncertainty is linear?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59628/) Also related: [How to combine measurement error with statistic error](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23441/), [How to combine the error of two independent measurements of the same quantity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23643/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to round intermediate calculations. "Round to one significant figure" means that an error of 0.16 and 0.24 would propagate the same way when they are different by 50%.

Just don't *believe* the additional digits - but there is no reason to drop them.